# Adobe AIR app installer offline

Tags: actionscript-3, air, installation, adobe, offline

I'm making a software using AIR, and I got the installer installer.exe, but when I'm going to install in the target pcs, It tells me "This application requires a version of adobe air which cannot be found .....", but I need that my installer setup everything that I need to run my app in these pcs that have no Internet connection.

I'll appreciate any help !!
Greetings

Answer (score 0):

Just download the latest AIR installer on a PC with an internet connection, and bring that along with your AIR app installer. You can get it from http://get.adobe.com/air/

Answer (score 0):

From the research I've been doing, you can't legally include the runtime installer with your app unless you join adobe's [runtime distribution license](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime-distribution1.html).  If you look at the [Adobe Runtime Distribution FAQ](http://www.adobe.com/products/air/runtime-distribution-faq.html) that seems pretty close to what you are trying to do.